# Position of icons in vertical QToolbar when switching between Qt::ToolButtonIconOnly and Qt::ToolButtonTextBesideIcon

Tags: qt, icons, qtoolbar

When switching between `Qt::ToolButtonIconOnly` and `Qt::ToolButtonTextBesideIcon` in a vertical QToolBar, there is a slight shift of the icon to the right when expanding the toolbar:

[image: QToolBar]

Is it possible to get steady icons, which do not shift to the right like this?

[image: QToolBar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround with the stylesheet `QToolBar QToolButton { padding-right: 3px; }`.
To center the icon when the tabbar is closed, I added some spacing to the left of the icon itself.